# Check if the values are '|' separated in SQL string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a scenario where we need to check if string have '|' separated value or not if not then mark those rows as 'error'.

Dummy data is like --

```
create table test_2 (acc_no number, prod_svc varchar2(100), done varchar2(50));

insert into test_2 values (1001, '1234_first', null);
insert into test_2 values (1002, '1234_first|5678_secong', null);
insert into test_2 values (1001, '1234_first:5678_second', null);
```

Now among these 3 rows 1st two rows are not error while 3rd row is error as there is ':' as separator.

for that i have written a query which is working only when there are '|' but not when there is single value i.e. 1st row

```
update test_2
   set done = 'prevalidation-error'
where acc_no in(  select acc_no
                      from test_2
                     where instr(prod_svc, '|') < 1) ;
```

My this update statement is marking 1st and 3rd as error while it should not mark 1st row as error because that is only one value.
As we see my query is perfect for the scenario may be we need to write a PLSQL block for that but still i ma not able to find out a way that how will i know if there is only 1 value for prod_svc column and that has to be correct!

I am using ---
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for any character other than a letter, digit, underscore, or vertical bar.  So use `regexp_like()`:

```
update test_2
   set done = 'prevalidation-error'
   where regexp_like(acc_no, '[^|a-zA-Z0-9_]');
```

Comment: But this statement is nnot marking the last row as error 
because that string is not separated by '|' it is using ':' as separator and also i think that is not acc_no but prod_svc !

Comment: @mradul did you test it? It does, because it does contain a character that is not in the range of `|a-zA-Z0-9_`, a `;` in this case

Comment: Yeah i test it but change the change the column name in regexp_like () to prod_svc and to my good 
IT IS WORKING :)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply you really help me solve a issue here :)
and it seems like  i need to work more on regexp

Comment: Hi Gordon i have a confusion that can we find strings from a column where the string contains only alphabets not any numeric value i.e. a pure a alphabet string not alphanumeric !!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to exclude delimiters for sample ',;:'

```
UPDATE test_2
   SET done = 'prevalidation-error'
 WHERE REGEXP_COUNT (prod_svc, '[,;:]') > 0
```

Comment: This is incorrect - it will mark the single-value string as "error." Why make it so complicated, and not regexp_count(prod_svc, ',;:') > 0 ?

Comment: @mathguy Error? Have you tested it? For the complication you have right. Repaired.

Comment: Uhm... no, I didn't, and now thinking back to it you are right, it was correct; for the single-value string, there would be no error, because there would be no splitting of the string (so the count would be 1). I stand corrected.

Comment: @mathguy :) Thanks. Next time you can edit direct my answer ;)

Comment: Err... I think it would have been less than six characters.  ;-)

Comment: Hi Mottor can we use this to search for a pure alphabet string not alphanumeric !